# How to get table value from query in vb6

Tags: vb6

I have created a table in vb6 function but unable to get its value from SQL query in vb6.I want auto incremented s.no instead of Months.The required table is given below.  Please help

```
S.NO  EMPLOYEE_ID  EMPLOYEE_NAME   GROSS_SALARY
1       1            abc             45677878
2       2            xyz             5678998
```

function is given below which is created

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

    Dim FileName As String
    Dim lTaxablePay As Variant
    Dim lSDLAmt As Variant
    Dim lRsCompDet As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim lRsMonthlyDet As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim lTotCasual As Currency, lTotPermanent As Currency, lTotSDLAmt As Currency, lTotGrossAmt As Currency

    Call MsgBox("This report will be generated for the period of " & MonthName(DTPFromDate.Month) & " to " & MonthName(DTPToDate.Month), vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, Me.Caption)

    lstrSQL = "SELECT ADDRESS1, ADDRESS2, CITY, POSTCODE , TYPE_OF_BUSINESS "
    lstrSQL = lstrSQL & " FROM I_HR_EMPLOYER_MASTER "
    lstrSQL = lstrSQL & " WHERE EMPLOYER_CODE = '" & gEmployerCode & "' AND TAX_YEAR = " & gTaxYear

    Set lRsCompDet = gObjDBConnection.ExecuteSQL(lstrSQL)

    If RecordsetsIsEmpty(lRsCompDet) = True Then
        MsgBox "Company Details are not entered.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, Me.Caption
        Exit Sub
    End If

    lTaxablePay = GetTaxablePay(, DTPFromDate.Month, DTPToDate.Month)
    lstrSQL = " SELECT s.EMPLOYEE_ID,EMPLOYEE_NAME, "
    lstrSQL = lstrSQL & " (SELECT sum(AMOUNT)As GROSS_SALARY FROM V_HR_PP_PROCESS_DATA  s inner join I_HR_EMPLOYEE_MASTER m on m.EMPLOYER_CODE=s.EMPLOYER_CODE and m.EMPLOYEE_ID=s.EMPLOYEE_ID WHERE "
    lstrSQL = lstrSQL & " EMPLOYER_CODE = A.EMPLOYER_CODE AND TAX_YEAR = A.TAX_YEAR AND PROCESS_MONTH = A.MONTH AND "
    lstrSQL = lstrSQL & " TAX_YEAR = 2014  "
    lstrSQL = lstrSQL & " group by  s.EMPLOYER_CODE,s.EMPLOYEE_ID,EMPLOYEE_NAME,TAX_YEAR "
   ' MsgBox (lstrSQL)


    Set lRsMonthlyDet = gObjDBConnection.ExecuteSQL(lstrSQL)

    lRsMonthlyDet.Sort = "Month Asc"

    'If fSDLPercentage <> 0 Then
        lSDLAmt = Val(lTaxablePay & "") * 1 / 100
   ' End If

 fObjTS.WriteLine " ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
    fObjTS.WriteLine " |              |                  |                 |                 |                        |"
    fObjTS.WriteLine " |   S.NO       |  EMPLOYEE_ID     |   EMPLOYEE NAME |   GROSS SALARY  | Total amount of        |"
    fObjTS.WriteLine " |              |                  |                 |                 | SDL. Paid to           |"
    fObjTS.WriteLine " |              |                  |                 |                 |  the Bank              |"
    fObjTS.WriteLine " ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"

    If RecordsetsIsEmpty(lRsMonthlyDet) = True Then
    fObjTS.WriteLine " |  January     |                  |                 |                 |                        |"
    fObjTS.WriteLine " |  February    |                  |                 |                 |                        |"
    fObjTS.WriteLine " |  March       |                  |                 |                 |                        |"
    fObjTS.WriteLine " |  April       |                  |                 |                 |                        |"
    fObjTS.WriteLine " |  May         |                  |                 |                 |                        |"
    fObjTS.WriteLine " |  June        |                  |                 |                 |                        |"
    fObjTS.WriteLine " |  July        |                  |                 |                 |                        |"
    fObjTS.WriteLine " |  August      |                  |                 |                 |                        |"
    fObjTS.WriteLine " |  September   |                  |                 |                 |                        |"
    fObjTS.WriteLine " |  October     |                  |                 |                 |                        |"
    fObjTS.WriteLine " |  November    |                  |                 |                 |                        |"
    fObjTS.WriteLine " |  December    |                  |                 |                 |                        |"
    fObjTS.WriteLine " |              |                  |                 |                 |                        |"
    fObjTS.WriteLine " ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
    fObjTS.WriteLine " |  TOTALS      |                  |                 |                 |                        |"
    fObjTS.WriteLine " ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
    Else

        lTotCasual = 0: lTotPermanent = 0: lTotSDLAmt = 0: lTotGrossAmt = 0
       Do While Not lRsMonthlyDet.EOF

            'If fSDLPercentage <> 0 Then
                lSDLAmt = (Val(lRsMonthlyDet.Fields("Gross_Permanent").Value & "") + Val(lRsMonthlyDet.Fields("Gross_Casual").Value & "")) * 1 / 100
           ' Else
           '     lSDLAmt = 0
          '  End If

            lTotCasual = lTotCasual + Val(lRsMonthlyDet.Fields("Employee_Id").Value & "")
           lTotPermanent = lTotPermanent + Val(lRsMonthlyDet.Fields("Employee_Name").Value & "")
            lTotGrossAmt = lTotGrossAmt + Val(lRsMonthlyDet.Fields("Gross_Salary").Value & "") + Val(lRsMonthlyDet.Fields("Gross_Permanent").Value & "")
            lTotSDLAmt = lTotSDLAmt + Val(lSDLAmt & "")

            fObjTS.WriteLine " |  " & _
                            ConvertNumberToThousandSeparator(Val(lRsMonthlyDet.Fields("Employee_Id").Value & "")) & "|" & _
                           ConvertNumberToThousandSeparator(Val(lRsMonthlyDet.Fields("Employee_Name").Value & "")) & "|" & _
                         ConvertNumberToThousandSeparator(Val(lRsMonthlyDet.Fields("Gross_Salary").Value & "")) & "|" & _
                            ConvertNumberToThousandSeparator(lSDLAmt, 24) & "|"

            lRsMonthlyDet.MoveNext

        Loop

        fObjTS.WriteLine " |              |                  |                 |                 |                        |"
        fObjTS.WriteLine " ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
        fObjTS.WriteLine " |  TOTALS      |" & _
                            ConvertNumberToThousandSeparator(Val(lTotPermanent & ""), 18) & "|" & _
                            ConvertNumberToThousandSeparator(Val(lTotCasual & ""), 17) & "|" & _
                            ConvertNumberToThousandSeparator(Val(lTotGrossAmt & ""), 17) & "|" & _
                            ConvertNumberToThousandSeparator(lTotSDLAmt, 24) & "|"
        fObjTS.WriteLine " ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"

   End If
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------
    fObjTS.WriteLine ""

    fObjTS.CLOSE

    Call ShowTextReportPreview(FileName)

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "unable to get its value from SQL Query" please?  It sounds like you're saying you're trying to get the value of the entire table and I'm having trouble making sense of that.

Comment: yea sure..@BobRodes. actually i want to get the table values , as you can see i have designed table .the field's value like EMPLOYEE_ID,EMPLOYEE_NAME,GROSS_SALARY should be come from database. query is ok..but i dont know how to fetch that data here in coding and also s.no should be auto incremented . Please help

Comment: I want result exactly i have described in table..

Comment: What does you code as it stands produce?

Comment: @Rob what you trying to say?  if you have solution then suggest please

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @BobRodes please help.

Comment: I deleted my answers - instead of correct using it you asked the same question again. Thanks for wasting my time.

Comment: @Kirat: what we are trying to say is that you need to give a more specific explanation of what happens than "unable to get its value from SQL query into VB6."  You're making me guess.  When you run ExecuteSQL does an error come up on that line?  Do you get an empty recordset when you are expecting something else?  And so on.  Please give the exact problem, if you want an exact explanation of what is wrong.

Comment: Thank you @BobRodes .its sorted out.i will explain next time more clearly question.you helped me alot in my last question too..:)

Comment: @Kirat it would be helpful to other people with the same problem if you would explain how you sorted it out by writing up an answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution for above problem

Private Sub cmdWCReport_Click()
        Dim FileName As String
    Dim lTaxablePay As Variant
    Dim lSDLAmt As Variant
    Dim lRsCompDet As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim lRsMonthlyDet As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim EmployeeID As String, EmployeeName As String, lTotBasicAmt As Currency, lTotGrossAmt As Currency, lTotUSDGrossPay As Currency

```
Call MsgBox("This report will be generated for the period of " & MonthName(DTPFromDate.Month), vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, Me.Caption)

lstrSQL = "SELECT ADDRESS1, ADDRESS2, CITY, POSTCODE , TYPE_OF_BUSINESS "
lstrSQL = lstrSQL & " FROM I_HR_EMPLOYER_MASTER "
lstrSQL = lstrSQL & " WHERE EMPLOYER_CODE = '" & gEmployerCode & "' AND TAX_YEAR = " & gTaxYear

Set lRsCompDet = gObjDBConnection.ExecuteSQL(lstrSQL)

If RecordsetsIsEmpty(lRsCompDet) = True Then
    MsgBox "Company Details are not entered.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, Me.Caption
    Exit Sub
End If

lTaxablePay = GetTaxablePay(, DTPFromDate.Month, DTPToDate.Month)

lstrSQL = " SELECT A.EMPLOYEE_ID, A.EMPLOYEE_CODE, A.EMPLOYEE_NAME, "
lstrSQL = lstrSQL & " (SELECT sum(AMOUNT) FROM V_HR_PP_PROCESS_DATA PP "
lstrSQL = lstrSQL & " WHERE EMPLOYER_CODE = A.EMPLOYER_CODE AND TAX_YEAR = " & gTaxYear & " AND PROCESS_MONTH = " & DTPFromDate.Month
lstrSQL = lstrSQL & " AND EMPLOYEE_ID = a.EMPLOYEE_ID AND PROCESS_YEAR = " & DTPFromDate.Year
lstrSQL = lstrSQL & " AND PD_CODE = 'Z970' ) as GROSSPAY, "
lstrSQL = lstrSQL & " (SELECT sum(AMOUNT) FROM V_HR_PP_PROCESS_DATA PP "
lstrSQL = lstrSQL & " WHERE EMPLOYER_CODE = A.EMPLOYER_CODE AND TAX_YEAR = " & gTaxYear & " AND PROCESS_MONTH = " & DTPFromDate.Month
lstrSQL = lstrSQL & " AND EMPLOYEE_ID = a.EMPLOYEE_ID AND PROCESS_YEAR = " & DTPFromDate.Year
lstrSQL = lstrSQL & " AND PD_CODE = 'Z001' ) as BASICPAY, "

 lstrSQL = lstrSQL & " (SELECT sum(AMOUNT_OTHER_CURRENCY) FROM V_HR_PP_PROCESS_DATA PP "
lstrSQL = lstrSQL & " WHERE EMPLOYER_CODE = A.EMPLOYER_CODE AND TAX_YEAR = " & gTaxYear & " AND PROCESS_MONTH = " & DTPFromDate.Month
lstrSQL = lstrSQL & " AND EMPLOYEE_ID = a.EMPLOYEE_ID AND PROCESS_YEAR = " & DTPFromDate.Year
lstrSQL = lstrSQL & " AND PD_CODE = 'Z970' AND OTHER_CURRENCY_CODE = 'USD') as USDGROSSPAY "

lstrSQL = lstrSQL & " FROM I_HR_EMPLOYEE_MASTER A"
lstrSQL = lstrSQL & " WHERE A.EMPLOYER_CODE = '" & gEmployerCode & "' "
lstrSQL = lstrSQL & " AND CURRENT_EMPLOYEE_STATUS <> 'T' AND RECORD_STATUS <> 'D'  "
'MsgBox (lstrSQL)

Set lRsMonthlyDet = gObjDBConnection.ExecuteSQL(lstrSQL)

'If fSDLPercentage <> 0 Then
    lSDLAmt = Val(lTaxablePay & "") * 1 / 100
```

' End If

On Error Resume Next
        fObjTS.Close

```
FileName = CreateStdSpoolFileName("WORKMEN'S COMPENSATION REPORT")
Set fObjTS = fobjSh.CreateTextFile(FileName, True)

'Set fObjTS = fobjSh.OpenTextFile(FileName, ForWriting,  True)

fObjTS.WriteLine ""
fObjTS.WriteLine "                          TANZANIA REVENUE AUTHORITY"
fObjTS.WriteLine "                             WC FUND"
fObjTS.WriteLine ""
fObjTS.WriteLine ""
fObjTS.WriteLine "                         WORKMEN'S COMPENSATION FUND(WCF)"
fObjTS.WriteLine "                      EMPLOYER 'S END OF THE YEAR CERTIFICATE"
fObjTS.WriteLine "                                 YEAR " & gTaxYear
fObjTS.WriteLine ""
fObjTS.WriteLine ""
fObjTS.WriteLine " To: The Regional/District Revenue Officer"
fObjTS.WriteLine "     Income Tax Department"
fObjTS.WriteLine "     P.O.Box............................."
fObjTS.WriteLine "            .............................  Employer's Income Tax Number " & fEmployersITNumber
fObjTS.WriteLine ""
fObjTS.WriteLine ""
fObjTS.WriteLine ""
fObjTS.WriteLine " -------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
fObjTS.WriteLine "|  1. Name Of Employer                 |" & PadR(gEmployerName, 39) & "|"
fObjTS.WriteLine "|                                      |                                       |"
fObjTS.WriteLine "|  2. Address: Postal                  |" & PadR(lRsCompDet.Fields("Address1").Value & "", 39) & "|"
fObjTS.WriteLine "|              Physical                |" & PadR(lRsCompDet.Fields("Address2").Value & "", 39) & "|"
fObjTS.WriteLine "|                                      |" & PadR(lRsCompDet.Fields("CITY").Value & "," & lRsCompDet.Fields("POSTCODE").Value, 39) & "|"
fObjTS.WriteLine "|  3. Nature of Business               |" & PadR(lRsCompDet.Fields("TYPE_OF_BUSINESS").Value & "", 39) & "|"
fObjTS.WriteLine "|                                      |                                       |"
fObjTS.WriteLine "|     State Whether                    |                                       |"
fObjTS.WriteLine "|  4. Individual/PartnerShips/         |                                       |"
fObjTS.WriteLine "|     Companies/                       |                                       |"
fObjTS.WriteLine "|     Parastatals/and others e.g Clubs |                                       |"
fObjTS.WriteLine "|     Trusts and Associations          |                                       |"
fObjTS.WriteLine "|  5. Amount                           |" & ConvertNumberToThousandSeparator(Val(lTaxablePay & ""), 16) & "                       |"
fObjTS.WriteLine "|  6. Applicable Month                 |" & DTPFromDate & "                            |"
fObjTS.WriteLine "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
fObjTS.WriteLine ""
fObjTS.WriteLine ""
fObjTS.WriteLine " The total amount of gross emoluments paid during the year " & gTaxYear & " added up"
fObjTS.WriteLine "to Shs " & ConvertNumberToThousandSeparator(Val(lTaxablePay & ""), 16) & " and " & 1 & "% of which works to Shs" & ConvertNumberToThousandSeparator(lSDLAmt, 16) & " as"
fObjTS.WriteLine "shown on the reverse of this Form."
fObjTS.WriteLine ""
fObjTS.WriteLine " I/We Certify that the particulars entered on the form HL.9 already submitted"
fObjTS.WriteLine "Monthly for the period from January to December, " & gTaxYear & " are correct."
fObjTS.WriteLine ""
fObjTS.WriteLine ""
fObjTS.WriteLine "Date " & Format(Date, "dd/MM/yyyy") & "                                 (Signature and rubber stamp)"
fObjTS.WriteLine ""
fObjTS.WriteLine "To be submitted in original to the relevant Income Tax Office on or before"
fObjTS.WriteLine "31St January of the Year following."

'Second Page
fObjTS.WriteLine Chr(12)
fObjTS.WriteLine "                                  SUMMARY FOR THE "
fObjTS.WriteLine "                                     YEAR " & gTaxYear
fObjTS.WriteLine ""
fObjTS.WriteLine ""

fObjTS.WriteLine " ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
fObjTS.WriteLine " |              |                  |                 |                 |                        |                |"
fObjTS.WriteLine " |   S.NO       |  EMPLOYEE_CODE   |   EMPLOYEE NAME |   GROSS SALARY  |  BASIC SALARY          |    USD_GROSS   |"
fObjTS.WriteLine " |              |                  |                 |                 |                        |                |"
fObjTS.WriteLine " |              |                  |                 |                 |                        |                |"
fObjTS.WriteLine " ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
```

lTotGrossAmt = 0: lTotBasicAmt = 0
        Dim lintCtr As Long
        lintCtr = 1

```
   Do While Not lRsMonthlyDet.EOF
        fObjTS.WriteLine " |  " & PadL(CStr(lintCtr), 5, False) & _
                        "       |  " & PadR(lRsMonthlyDet.Fields("EMPLOYEE_CODE").Value, 10) & _
                        "      |  " & PadR(lRsMonthlyDet.Fields("EMPLOYEE_NAME").Value, 10) & _
                        "     |  " & ConvertNumberToThousandSeparator(Val(lRsMonthlyDet.Fields("GROSSPAY").Value & ""), 15) & _
                        "|  " & ConvertNumberToThousandSeparator(Val(lRsMonthlyDet.Fields("BASICPAY").Value & ""), 22) & _
                         "|  " & ConvertNumberToThousandSeparator(Val(lRsMonthlyDet.Fields("USDGROSSPAY").Value & ""), 8) & "      |"


        lTotGrossAmt = lTotGrossAmt + Val(lRsMonthlyDet.Fields("GROSSPAY").Value & "")
        lTotBasicAmt = lTotBasicAmt + Val(lRsMonthlyDet.Fields("BASICPAY").Value & "")
        lTotUSDGrossPay = lTotUSDGrossPay + Val(lRsMonthlyDet.Fields("USDGROSSPAY").Value & "")


            lRsMonthlyDet.MoveNext
            lintCtr = lintCtr + 1
    Loop

    fObjTS.WriteLine " |              |                  |                 |                 |                        |                |"
    fObjTS.WriteLine " -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
    fObjTS.WriteLine " |  TOTALS      |" & _
                         " " & "                 |" & _
                      " " & "                |" & _
        ConvertNumberToThousandSeparator(Val(lTotGrossAmt), 16) & " |" & _
        ConvertNumberToThousandSeparator(Val(lTotBasicAmt), 24) & "|" & _
         ConvertNumberToThousandSeparator(Val(lTotUSDGrossPay), 10) & "       |"
    fObjTS.WriteLine " -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
```

fObjTS.Close

```
Call ShowTextReportPreview(FileName)
```

End Sub
}